VM not booting with UEFI
When setting up a Windows 11 VM, using VMware Workstation Pro 17.5.2 on a Windows 11 host, one can go to VM tab, Settings, Options tab, Advanced, and choose Firmware type: BIOS or UEFI with Secure Boot.
If I choose UEFI with Secure Boot, the VM will not start the Windows 11 installation. I only get a blue rectangle with “Boot Manager” written on top of it.
But if I remove TPM, under the Hardware tab in Settings, and then go to Advanced, under the Option tab, I can choose BIOS, and then Windows 11 begins to install with no problems, though I must go into Regedit to bypass the product key requirement despite having a valid key for Windows 10.
Firstly, how can I get the VM to work with UEFI and Secure Boot?
Secondly, when learning malware analysis, is it safer to use UEFI with Secure Boot or is BIOS safe enough?
Thirdly, is it safe to install Windows 11 as a VM without entering in the product key during installation?

You need to enable Secure Boot and UEFI with TPM enabled and reinstall Windows 11.  It appears Windows 11 was installed in Legacy Mode. You might be able to use MBR2GPT.  However, without additional information, it's difficult to provide better diagnostic suggestions.

“It appears Windows 11 was installed in Legacy Mode.”
Are you referring to the guest OS? I’m new to VM’s, so don’t know what Legacy Mode means in this context.
When setting up the VM, I chose ISO and installed this file from downloads in the host OS:
Win11_23H2_EnglishInternational_x64v2

The only way Windows can boot with Secure Boot and UEFI disabled on a VM is if it was installed in Legacy Mode. You need to view the system properties, and edit your question, and indicate if the VM is configured in UEFI or Legacy Mode.

System Information of the VM says: BIOS Mode Legacy. The BIOS Mode of the host is UEFI.

So you installed Windows in Legacy Mode.  You will want to enable UEFI on the VM then reinstall Windows on the VM. What you want cannot be salvaged.

Welcome to SuperUser. Please note that we ask that each post contain only a single question. This is so that a single good answer can be marked as such, keeping with the "Question and Answer" nature of this site. Regarding your second question, you should probably do some research regarding this. If you do research and find a point you are having trouble understanding, THAT may be a question we can help you with. We aren't here to do your research for you, to put it one way. Regarding your third question, is there a reason you believe it may be unsafe not entering a key?

As mentioned in OP: “If I choose UEFI with Secure Boot, the VM will not start the Windows 11 installation. I only get a blue rectangle with “Boot Manager” written on top of it.“ Is there another way to choose UEFI instead of Legacy mode? I assume Legacy mode is what I get when choosing BIOS and not UEFI in Advanced settings, right?

@ingenting - "Is there another way to choose UEFI instead of Legacy mode?" - No; If Legacy Mode is disabled then UEFI is enabled, or specifically, if UEFI mode is enabled Legacy Mode is disabled.  If Windows was installed while the VM was configured to use a BIOS firmware configuration on a MBR VHDD, then it was installed in Legacy Mode. "I assume Legacy mode is what I get when choosing BIOS and not UEFI in Advanced settings, right?" - Your assumption in incorrect.

@ingenting - "Press any key to boot from CD or DVD... EFI Network Time out." - You made mention of this issue in a comment, but your question makes no mention of this fact.  You indicated that the VM turns on with UEFI firmware, but Windows does not. Boot Manager would point to a Windows configuration mix match with the VM configuration (UEFI vs BIOS). I went ahead and deleted my answer because your question does not contain enough information to accurately answer your question.  As evident by your commentary to my answer. I also won't be coming back to this question.

You wrote:
“You need to enable Secure Boot and UEFI with TPM enabled”
In the Hardware tab of my VM on VMware Workstation Pro, it says: Trusted Platform Module: Present. In the Options tab, under Advanced, it says: Firmware type: UEFI and Enable secure boot. Have always checked both. Since I checked UEFI, and has TPM enabled, the whole area under Firmware type is greyed out. But the VM will not launch Windows 11.

It’s only when I remove TPM and enable BIOS that Windows 11 launches in the VM. Others also have this problem. Just watch YT videos like this one: EFI Network Time out issue in Vmware https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=roOo3vnUJiY

The answer OP has posted indicates their question remains very unclear, as what is in the main question body does not get "solved" by the information given in the answer, which is simply a description of a normal part of booting to media on virtual and physical computers.

At no point in your question did you say you were having problems installing Windows. When I asked if you were booting Windows in Legacy Mode or UEFI, you indicated you were booting in Legacy Mode, which suggests Windows was installed. Had I known you were having problems installing Windows on a VM, I could have asked different questions and then submitted an appropriately detailed answer. Booting to the installation media isn't anything unique to a virtual machine. You have to do that on a physical machine also.

In the OP, I wrote: “If I choose UEFI with Secure Boot, the VM will not start the Windows 11 installation.” But that’s fine. Troubleshooting this would have been difficult in any case, since who in this forum would keep in mind that one must left-click on the above-mentioned black screen and hit enter? It’s a tiny detail, but crucial  :)

@ingenting - Super User isn’t a forum

Found the answer here, though not easy to see:
HOW TO Install Windows 11: VMware Workstation
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=EMuw_IN-UOU
When you power on the VM, you get a black screen, and you will see this text:
Press any key to boot from CD or DVD...
Quickly left-click on the black screen and then hit enter. Windows 11 will then begin to install.

That's completely normal to booting to a CD (or USB) for any computer, physical or virtual. Based on this being the answer, I believe that while you THINK you have given us an accurate description of the problem, you may have missed several key bits of information.

I’m new to VMs, so I don’t assume accuracy. Installing a host OS via a real UEFI looks very different from a relatively small black screen in a VM that you must click on twice to activate the installation. In two posts that got deleted when another user deleted his post, I did describe the whole installation process, including what I saw on the black screen. But I’m just a noob who is happy to have found a solution, so have no need to discuss this anymore. Let’s just say that you were right, and I was wrong  :)  :)
